# Call local host server with parameters

Tags: flask

I am running the Flask server on port 81. I want my server to show a normal page at `/` and a debug page at `/debug`. When I enter `localhost:81` I get the normal page. When I try to navigate to `localhost\debug:81` or `localhost/81:81` I get a "Not Found" error. What am I doing wrong?

```
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/debug')
def index_debug():
    return render_template('index.html', debug=true)
```

Comment: The URL you use in the browser has to be **localhost:81/debug** for your debug endpoint

Comment: Also tried it.
It did not work, I am still getting "Not Found"  error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have the project structure like this:

```js
index.py
templates/
      index.html
```

and your param debug has to be debug=**True**